# Are vb.net eventArgs maintained at a "system" level?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a custom developed control I am using that somebody else wrote.  For some reason, when the control was written, they did not write an event handler for the "mouseDown" event so when I mouseDown on the control, no event is fired.  What I am basically trying to do is capture which mouse button (left or right) is pressed when the control is clicked on.  Is there any sort of system level objects that maintain system state (including which mouse buttons are currently being pressed regardless of the control being clicked upon?)

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms control?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to wrap the control in a way that gives you the MouseDown functionality?

Comment: How would I wrap the control to give me the mouseDown functionality.  I think that might work.  Is that with an "AddHandler"?